# iOS: Draw "Movable Polygon" with Core Graphics

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-graphics, draw

I would like to draw a UIBerzierPath (e.g. a Rectangle with 4 CGPoints) in Core Graphics and and change its position, maybe also its size (e.g. bigger width, smaller height), which means, the four Points of the UIBerzierPath change.

How can I get this change in appearance as animation (so that the points and edges move to its new position), instead of just drawing the new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a CAShapeLayer

```
let pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
pathLayer.path = path.cgPath
pathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

pathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
pathLayer.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
pathLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

self.view.layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)
```

Animate it like so:

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
animation.toValue = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100)).cgPath
animation.duration = 1
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
pathLayer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
```